Free Netlist extractor from Schematic for ngSpice Simulation
I have been using xcircuit to extract netlists from schematics, but it seems to give errors in the extracted netlist. I am looking for free and robust alternatives to xcircuit to generate netlist, that works in Linux. Also, I would like to know about free Verilog-AMS or Verilog-A simulators for Linux.
